# Dynamically generate table and then add td based upon some condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have javascript method where based on condition I add table and tr. Then based on other condition I call another javascript method where I want to add new td each time.

I looked at this link http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-insert-td-before-previous-td

But here td is added before to any other td and I want to add on some condition after previous td. If there is any jquery way plz let me know.

Comment: can we see your html and jQuery functions that you have created.?

Comment: If `insertBefore` inserts before, I guess looking at the API documentation will help you to find a method to `append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this example;

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>cell1</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
</br><a id="clickme">clickme</a>


$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $('<td>cell</td>').appendTo('#mytable tr');
    i++;
});
```

When you click the link, it will add new `<td>` to the row, next to the current `<td>`.

Here is a **[working live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg2tm/1/)**.

You may customize this according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. How can I add table?

Comment: use `$('<table id="mytable"><tr></tr></table>').appendTo('body');`